# How to get records based on nearest greater value

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics

The Table contains data as below

Note - Running Total is calculated with respect to Part

| Part | Quantity | Running Total | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 5 | 5 | 45 |
| ABC | 10 | 15 | 45 |
| ABC | 12 | 27 | 45 |
| ABC | 16 | 43 | 45 |
| ABC | 10 | 53 | 45 |
| ABC | 5 | 58 | 45 |
| DEF | 5 | 5 | 15 |
| DEF | 10 | 15 | 15 |
| DEF | 10 | 25 | 15 |
| DEF | 5 | 30 | 15 |

The requirement is to fetch records where the running total should be the equal or nearest greater value with respect to stock. In the table, For Part ABC the stock value is 45. 53 is the nearest number greater than 45. For Part DEF the Stock value 15. So the Output should be

| Part | Quantity | Running Total | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 5 | 5 | 45 |
| ABC | 10 | 15 | 45 |
| ABC | 12 | 27 | 45 |
| ABC | 16 | 43 | 45 |
| ABC | 10 | 53 | 45 |
| DEF | 5 | 5 | 15 |
| DEF | 10 | 15 | 15 |

Comment: To compute a running total you need to have a sorting criteria for each part. It's not clear to me how are you sorting rows.

Comment: The running total is been calculated and captured based on date. Have to use the existing table and get the output as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly a correlated subquery is one of a few methods you could use:

```
select * 
from t
where running_total - stock <= (
    select Min(t2.running_total - t2.stock)
    from t t2 
    where t.part = t2.part and t2.running_total - t2.stock >= 0
);
```

Comment: Does `< =` work, or should it be typed as `<=`? That space right there hurts my eyes.

Comment: @TheImpaler Lol it works but I agree and have amended :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `LAG` function

```
SELECT
    part,
    quantity,
    running_total,
    stock
FROM (   
SELECT 
    *,
    LAG(running_total, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY running_total) AS prev_running_total
FROM parts
) t
WHERE prev_running_total < stock
```

Output:

| part | quantity | running_total | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 5 | 5 | 45 |
| ABC | 10 | 15 | 45 |
| ABC | 12 | 27 | 45 |
| ABC | 16 | 43 | 45 |
| ABC | 10 | 53 | 45 |
| DEF | 5 | 5 | 15 |
| DEF | 10 | 15 | 15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eebd77e0951a9a2246ec373c16395c46)

Comment: It would not ;)

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe `<=` in the last line?